# No display output in 20.04 when resuming suspend

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, graphics

I'm almost at a loss here: sometimes (and only sometimes) I will have no display output from my graphics card (RTX3060) when trying to resume from sleep. I have an Asus TUF b550, ryzen 5 5600x and asus rtx 3060 LHR.

Ubuntu 20.04,
Kernel version: 5.11.0-38

I have tried the following:

- update BIOS
- reseat all the cables
- try alternative PCIe slot for the GPU
- try alternative output ports from the GPU (since my CPU doesn't have an integrated graphics processor, I can't use the integrated ports of the motherboard)
- install nvidia drivers

Is there any software setting that might help me? I suspect that it might be related to power management